# Is a same value of a field tokenized each time for elasticsearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, opensearch, amazon-opensearch

I have a usecase where there is a field in each document of an elasticsearch cluster which has same values in most cases. I have to use search-as-you-type on this field.
I wanted to check if during tokenization, if value of a field in multiple documents the same, say value of field X is "ABC" in 100 documents, are tokens generated for each document? Wanted to ensure that we are not drastically increasing elasticsearch cluster size due to this change

Answer (score 0):

A very simple test... is to test :-)

Here is a quick example that shows you how that works.
First, we create a test index with a single `completion` field and we index once document in it. Note that it behaves the same way with the `search_as_you_type` field type.

```
PUT test 
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "text": {
        "type": "completion"
      }
    }
  }
}

POST test/_bulk
{"index":{}}
{"text": "Lorem ipsum dolor"}
```

After this, let's check the completion statistics of the index:

```
GET test/_stats?filter_path=**.completion

=> Returns
{
  "_all" : {
    "primaries" : {
      "completion" : {
        "size_in_bytes" : 128
      }
    },
    "total" : {
      "completion" : {
        "size_in_bytes" : 256
      }
    }
  },
  "indices" : {
    "test" : {
      "primaries" : {
        "completion" : {
          "size_in_bytes" : 128
        }
      },
      "total" : {
        "completion" : {
          "size_in_bytes" : 256
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then, index some more documents **with the exact same content**:

```
POST test/_bulk
{"index":{}}
{"text": "Lorem ipsum dolor"}
{"index":{}}
{"text": "Lorem ipsum dolor"}
{"index":{}}
{"text": "Lorem ipsum dolor"}
... 100 times ...
{"index":{}}
{"text": "Lorem ipsum dolor"}
```

Let's get the stats again, and guess what, the **heap usage increases**, which should answer your question:

```
GET test/_stats?filter_path=**.completion

=> Returns
{
  "_all" : {
    "primaries" : {
      "completion" : {
        "size_in_bytes" : 665
      }
    },
    "total" : {
      "completion" : {
        "size_in_bytes" : 1330
      }
    }
  },
  "indices" : {
    "test" : {
      "primaries" : {
        "completion" : {
          "size_in_bytes" : 665
        }
      },
      "total" : {
        "completion" : {
          "size_in_bytes" : 1330
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```